# 16-bit Assembly on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, x86-16, incompatibility

I decided to start learning assembly a while ago, and so I started with 16-bit assembly, using [FASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASM).

However, I recently got a really new computer running Windows 7 64-bit, and now none of the compiled .COM files that the program assembles work any more. They give an error message, saying that the .COM is not compatible with 64-bit however.

32-bit assemblies still work, however I'd rather start with 16 and work my way up...

Is it possible to run a 16-bit program on windows 7? Or is there a specific way to compile them? Or should I give up and skip to 32-bit instead?

Comment: You could always run a VM for your target environment.

Comment: Assembly is _processor_ specific. What processor are you using? What processor were you using?

Comment: A VM like Windows Virtual PC. But this question is mislead anyways as there is no working up from 16-bits. 64-bit mode is far simpler and similar enough to 32-bits that you don't need to learn the latter specifically either. More bits != harder

Comment: Related: [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1029093) for 32-bit examples of calling WinAPI functions in kernel32.dll

Answer (score 9):

The reason you can't use 16-bit assembly is because the [16-bit subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTVDM) [has been removed](https://web.archive.org/web/20110804173530/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946765) from all 64-bit versions of Windows.

The only way to remedy this is to install something like [DOSBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox), or a virtual machine package such as [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and then install [FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS) into that. That way, you get true DOS anyway. ([NTVDM is not true DOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20080625040650/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/24/6849530.aspx#6858343).)

Personally, would I encourage writing 16-bit assembly for DOS? No. I'd use 32- or even 64-bit assembly, the reason being there are a different set of function calls for different operating systems (called the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)). So, the ABI for 64-bit Linux applications is different to 32-bit ones. I am not sure if that's the case with Windows. However, I guarantee that the meaning of interrupts is probably different.

Also, you've got all sorts of things to consider with 16-bit assembly, like the [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Memory_models) in use. I might be wrong, but I believe DOS gives you 64K memory to play with "and that's it". Everything, your entire heap and stack along with code must fit into this space, as I understand it, which makes you wonder how anything ever worked, really.

Comment: To your pondering about 64K memory being sufficient, you should check out the demoscene -> http://www.demoscene.info/

Comment: Inaccurate (but not your fault). It has been removed since it won't work properly under Long Mode. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realise that was the reason for its removal, I just knew it had been binned by Microsoft. Not a bad move as far as I'm concerned, we really shouldn't be using WOW64 any more either.

Comment: So will things like DOS-based cross-compilers no longer work?  Sounds like a good reason not to go to 64-bit.  I wonder why Microsoft didn't provide an emulation layer for DOS stuff?  Even doing per-instruction emulation, it would still let DOS software run faster on a new machine than it would have run on the machines for which it was written.

Answer (score 7):

My advice would be to just write 32-bit code. While it might initially seem like it would make sense to learn how to write 16-bit code, then "graduate" to 32-bit code, I'd say in reality rather the opposite is true: writing 32-bit code is actually easier because quite a few arbitrary architectural constraints (e.g., on what you can use as a base register) are basically gone in 32-bit code.

For that matter, I'd consider it open to substantial question whether there's ever a real reason to write 16-bit x86 code at all. For most practical purposes, it's a dead platform -- for desktop machines it's *seriously* obsolete, and for embedded machines, you're more likely to see things like ARMs or Microchip PICs. Unless you have a specific target in mind and know for sure that it's going to be a 16-bit x86, I'd probably forget that it existed, just like most of the rest of the world has.

Comment: +1, I was going to mention embedded but I don't know enough about it from the assembly standpoint. Well said r.e. learning curve too.

Answer (score 1):

[32-bit Windows 7 and older include / enable NTVDM by default.  On 32-bit Win8+, you can enable it in Windows Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597600/assembly-programming-for-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment62905377_29597600).

On 64-bit Windows (or any other 64-bit OS), you need an emulator or full virtualization.

A kernel in long mode *can't* use vm86 mode to provide a virtual 8086 real-mode environment.  This is a limitation of the AMD64 / x86-64 architecture.

With a 64-bit kernel running, the only way for your CPU to natively run in 16-bit mode is 16-bit *protected* mode (yes this exists; no, nobody uses it, and AFAIK mainstream OSes don't provide a way to use it).  Or for the kernel to switch the CPU out of long mode back to legacy mode, but 64-bit kernels don't do that.

But actually, with hardware virtualization (VirtualBox, Hyper-V or whatever using Intel VT-x or AMD SVM), **a 64-bit kernel can be the hypervisor for an entire virtual machine**, whether that VM is running in 16-bit real mode or running a 32-bit OS (like Windows 98 or 2000) which can in turn use vm86 mode to run 16-bit real-mode executables.

Especially on a 64-bit kernel, **it's usually easier to just emulate a 16-bit PC entirely (like DOSBOX does)**, instead of using HW virtualization to running normal instructions natively but trap direct hardware access (`in` / `out`, loads/stores to VGA memory, etc.) and `int` instructions that make DOS system calls / BIOS calls / whatever.