# Assembly programming for Windows 7

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I have been trying to learn assembly but have been having issues implementing the code.

```
org 100h
mov dx,string
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h
string db 'Hello, World',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
```

I am using Nasm to assemble the code. In the command line I type `nasm hello.asm -o hello.com` then I type `hello` and it shows an `error: unsupported 16bit application`. I'm using windows 7 64-bit ultimate.

I have also tried just typing `nasm hello.asm` and it says: `hello.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected`.

Anyway I would like to use Nasm with Alink and GoLink instead of Masm even though I have been able to implement some code with masm. That code was in my opinion more high level code than the code above.

If anyone has an idea why it's doing this or can post a template of code for nasm it would great. Or better yet suggest a site that I can use as a tutorial would be great. I have looked on Google and YouTube but most of the stuff is for Linux and my machine can't run Linux at this time. I am looking into Cygwin to help with that problem.

Comment: You probably have a very old assembly language reference.  The message means exactly what it says.  .COM files don't work with WIn 7 and later. Get a newer reference that shows how to build .EXE files. A quick check turned up this, but I'm sure there are better: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1559-compiling-an-assembly-program-with-nasm

Comment: See specifically [**7.6 win64: Microsoft Win64 Object Files**](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.6) (example provided)

Comment: For to execute DOS based software interrupts use the "DOSBOX" [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/dosbox/0.74/DOSBox0.74-win32-installer.exe/download or boot a DOS from USB-Stick/BootCD: [link]http://www.freedos.org/download/

Comment: @Gene not entirely correct. 16-bit Windows application will run on 32-bit Windows with Microsofts' NTVDM environment from NT all the way through to 32-bit Windows 10. On Windows 8+ you need to enable it via windows features.

Comment: 64-bit Windows of course is a different story.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes I've been running exclusively 64-bit Windows. Did not know NTVDM was still there in 32-bit. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Is [16-bit Assembly on 64-bit Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3620670) a good canonical duplicate for this?  Could maybe use an answer about which versions of Windows NTDVM *is* supported on, but otherwise looks good for duphammering SO's `.com`-won't-run or "this old tutorial" questions

Comment: @PeterCordes NTVDM versions would rarely pose an issue (if any at all). I'd say it is a reasonable answer on that other question.