# Is Virtual 8086 Mode or Real Mode in ring -1 available when using virtualization on a 64 Bit host OS that runs in long mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, x86-16, qemu, virtualization, kvm

I know that virtual 8086 mode and real mode mode is not available in long mode on a 64 Bit host OS on a x86-64 CPU. But is this also valid for a virtualized guest OS that run in ring -1 using virtualization (VT-x or AMD-V)?

Comment: I do believe they are (both) available. For example, dosemu2 can use KVM (using SVM) in Linux (on an amd64, long mode host) to run a 86 Mode client.

Comment: Yes, a guest VM can be in any mode, not constrained by the mode of the hypervisor.  I didn't find an exact duplicate, but  [16-bit Assembly on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125413) mentions that fact.